# Custom List view off screen positions

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom list view, which includes items that has functionality to swipe left or right...
The problem is that when I swipe visible items on the list view, off screen items also swipe left or right as respectively. How can I prevent swipe of off screen items?

```
public class TestListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<RowItem> arrayList;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public TestListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<RowItem> arrayList,DataSource dataSource){
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList =arrayList;

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.handle_c);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtTitle.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());

         if(arrayList.get(position).getleft()) {
                //txtTitle.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                setMargins(holder.txtTitle, px2dp(55), 0, 0,0);


            }else {
                //txtTitle.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                setMargins(holder.txtTitle, 0,0,px2dp(55),0);
            }



        convertView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(context) {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft(View view) {
                if (arrayList.get(position).getleft()){
                    arrayList.get(position).setleft(false);
                    Animation animationtranslate_left = new TranslateAnimation(px2dp(55+arrayList.get(position).getPX()),px2dp(0+arrayList.get(position).getPX()),0,0);
                    animationtranslate_left.setDuration(100);
                    //animationtranslate.setFillAfter(true);

                    //Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.left_swipe);
                    try {
                        view.clearAnimation();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    if (view != null)
                        view.startAnimation(animationtranslate_left);
                    else
                        Log.e("View null", "Null");
                    animationtranslate_left.setFillAfter(true);

              }

            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight(View view) {
                if (!arrayList.get(position).getleft()) {
                    arrayList.get(position).setleft(true);
                    Animation animationtranslate_rigth = new TranslateAnimation(px2dp(0+arrayList.get(position).getPX()),px2dp(55+arrayList.get(position).getPX()),0 , 0);
                    animationtranslate_rigth. setDuration(100);
                    //animationtranslate.setFillAfter(true);

                    //Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.left_swipe);
                    try {
                        view.clearAnimation();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    if (view != null)
                        view.startAnimation(animationtranslate_rigth);
                    else
                        Log.e("View null", "Null");
                    animationtranslate_rigth.setFillAfter(true);


            }


        });





        return convertView;
    }

    private class Detector extends GestureDetector {

        View view;

        public Detector(Context context, OnGestureListener listener) {
            super(context, listener);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent ev, View view) {
            this.view = view.findViewById(R.id.handle_c);
            return onTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        public View getView() {
            return view;
        }

        private void setView(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

    }


    public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

        private final Detector gestureDetector;

        public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
            gestureDetector = (Detector) new Detector(context, new GestureListener());
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft(View view) {

        }

        public void onSwipeRight(View view) {
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouch(event, v);
        }

        private final class GestureListener extends Detector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

            //private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 20;
            //private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
            //private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                float ydis = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
                if (ydis > 70) {
                    return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
                } else {
                    if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > 0) {
                        onSwipeLeft(gestureDetector.getView());
                    } else if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() < 0) {
                        onSwipeRight(gestureDetector.getView());
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                try {

                    System.out.println("X1-  " + e1.getX() + " X2-  " + e2.getX() + " Y1-  " + e1.getY() + " Y2-  " + e2.getY());
                    if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > 0) {
                        onSwipeLeft(gestureDetector.getView());
                    } else if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() < 0) {
                        onSwipeRight(gestureDetector.getView());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Home", "Error on gestures");
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView txtTitle;
    }


    public class RowItem {
    private String title,id,name,number,primeri_id;
    private boolean left;
    private int px;
    public boolean getleft(){return  left;}
    public int getPX(){return  px;}
    public void setleft(boolean b){left=b;}
    public RowItem(boolean bl,String t,String id,String primeri_id){
        title=t;
        left=bl;
        this.id = id;
        this.primeri_id = primeri_id;
        px=bl? -55:0;
    }
    public RowItem(String name ,String number){
        this.name = name;
        this.number= number;

    }

    public String getPrimeri_id() {
        return primeri_id;
    }

    public void setPrimeri_id(String primeri_id) {
        this.primeri_id = primeri_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem is caused by the fact that ListView rows are recycled. They are more like masks your individual data get to wear when they appear on the screen. So you have to leave them alone, which means after each animation you write (the same for '...right...'):

```
animationtranslate_left.setFillAfter(false);
```

In order to achieve a persisting change of position for your text, I used a simple workaround (one could also define different types of row layout):

I made list_item.xml a LinearLayout with two TextViews:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/handle_c_left"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/handle_c_right"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and likewise changed the ViewHolder:

```
    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView txtTitle_1;
        TextView txtTitle_2;
    }
```

In the 'getView()' method I added:

```
        if(arrayList.get(position).getleft()) {
            holder.txtTitle_1.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.txtTitle_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.txtTitle_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }else {
            holder.txtTitle_2.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.txtTitle_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.txtTitle_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

and as last statement in each 'OnSwipe...()' method I inserted

```
  notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Because of the changed list_item.xml one has to change 'gestureDetector.onTouch()' as well. I patched it like this:

```
  public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent ev, View view) {
         //this.view = view.findViewById(R.id.handle_c);
         this.view = view;
         return onTouchEvent(ev);
  }
```

Without knowing all your code it's difficult to decide wether the patch is ok and without the 'px2dp()' I'm sure I didn't hit the distances exactly. But I've tested it and it worked.

The important points are:

- it's no use making animation effects permanent when working with list rows
- List items are maintained by the adapter to show you the underlying data. When there are changes to the data, call 'notifyDatasetChanged()' and let the adapter do its job.